# Teacher salaries VS Teachers' salary : What is the difference?

Tags: word-usage

When I am reading **[this secretly ongoing controvertial issue in NC,](http://edition.cnn.com/2016/03/23/politics/north-carolina-gender-bathrooms-bill/index.html)**

A U.S representative in, as in the quote,

> U.S. Rep. David Price, D-North Carolina, also chastised the Legislature for prioritizing passing the bill over other issues.
>
> "The #NCGA won't hold a special session to raise teacher salaries, but they will come back to legislate discrimination? Enough is enough," he tweeted Wednesday.

I am just subtly perplexed what is the difference when this democratic representative said, "teacher salaries".

To me, personally, "teachers' salary" sounds more accurate to me.

Am I wrong here?

Comment: "teacher salary" is a **noun adjunct** phrase, in which a noun is used like an adjective: http://www.englishcorner.vacau.com/grammar/rules/nounadj.html

Comment: A must read at [Englishclub](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/nouns-adjective.htm) And a word of advice: [Don't accept an answer too soon](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer)

Comment: Is "bathroom bill" also a noun adjunct phrase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the quote given, the noun "teacher" serves as an adjective modifying "salary." (Ask yourself, what kind of salary? The salary of a teacher.)  Saying "teacher salaries" is proper, and most likely preferred in this context.

Saying "teachers' salaries" would also be correct, although adding a possessive apostrophe to a word that already ends in an 's' is awkward to pronounce in spoken English.

I would not use singular "salary" to describe the collective paychecks of a group of teachers. Since we consider each salary to be an individual and unique amount, use a plural "salaries" to refer to the collective pay of many individuals.

Comment: Thank you. Though I am sorry to say, when you said, "I would not use singular "salary" to describe the collective paychecks of a group of teachers." , the adjective "collective" could mean "teachers" in my personal assumption.

Comment: It's even more awkward when the subsequent word begins with an s. In this case I suspect the pronunciation difficulties caused the s's to be dropped completely.